# Getting 500 error code while navigating to a new page

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jspx

I tried using conventional method of navigation rules in ADF but it's not working. Probably because it's `jspx` not `jsf` pages.

Well I wrote a code that triggers on Action on button click. Below is the code in bean class's method:

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2", "InfoBox: " + "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest();
//Commented as authentication not required:
/* CallbackHandler handler = new SimpleCallbackHandler(un, pw);
Subject mySubject = Authentication.login(handler);
ServletAuthentication.runAs(mySubject, request);
ServletAuthentication.generateNewSessionID(request);*/

String loginUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:7101/ServiceCloudJavaApp/faces/ServiceRequests.jspx";
ctx.getViewRoot().getViewId();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();
sendForward(request, response, loginUrl);

.........
}

private void sendForward(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String loginUrl) {

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(loginUrl);
    try
    {
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    catch (ServletException se)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, se.toString(), "InfoBox: " + "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    catch (IOException ie)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ie.toString(), "InfoBox: " + "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    catch (Exception excep)
    {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exep.toString(), "InfoBox: " + "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("error:" + excep.toString());
    }
    ctx.responseComplete();
}
```

I'm getting webpage cannot be displayed! **Error code: 500**

Error log is here: http://textuploader.com/52wh3

```
<oracle.adf.view> <RichExceptionHandler> <_reportFailureForMissingViewRoot> <ADF_FACES-30200:For more information, please see the server's error log for an entry beginning with: The UIViewRoot is null. Fatal exception during PhaseId: RESTORE_VIEW 1.> 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: MDSLockedSessionManager already registered. Can't register more than one.
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.mds.LockedTransactionManager.<init>(LockedTransactionManager.java:27)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$1.before(ADFPhaseListener.java:322)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.beforePhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:77)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.beforePhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:44)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:356)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:588)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:273)
    at com.oracle.pts.view.ClickCreateNew.sendForward(ClickCreateNew.java:200)
    at com.oracle.pts.view.ClickCreateNew.ClickedCreate(ClickCreateNew.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: MDSLockedSessionManager already registered. Can't register more than one.
    at oracle.adf.share.mds.MDSTransManager.registerMDSLockedSessionManagerInst(MDSTransManager.java:131)
    at oracle.adf.share.mds.MDSTransManager.registerMDSLockedSessionManager(MDSTransManager.java:123)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.mds.LockedTransactionManager.<init>(LockedTransactionManager.java:23)
    ... 85 more
<oracle.adf.view> <RichExceptionHandler> <_logUnhandledException> <ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase INVOKE_APPLICATION 5> 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.context.JSFRequestMapAdapter.getRequestMap(JSFRequestMapAdapter.java:29)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.context.LifecycleContextHelper.getRequestMap(LifecycleContextHelper.java:72)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.context.LifecycleContextHelper.getLifecycleContext(LifecycleContextHelper.java:36)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.getLifecycleContext(ADFPhaseListener.java:167)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.dispatchAfterPagePhaseEvent(ADFPhaseListener.java:302)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:88)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:489)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
<oracle.adf.common> <ADFContext> <getCurrent> <Automatically initializing a DefaultContext for getCurrent.
Caller should ensure that a DefaultContext is proper for this use.
Memory leaks and/or unexpected behaviour may occur if the automatic initialization is performed improperly.
This message may be avoided by performing initADFContext before using getCurrent().
For more information please enable logging for oracle.adf.share.ADFContext at FINEST level.> 
<Feb 26, 2016 1:52:07 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@2080288141[app:TestADFJavaApp module:ServiceCloudJavaApp path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.context.JSFRequestMapAdapter.getRequestMap(JSFRequestMapAdapter.java:29)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.context.LifecycleContextHelper.getRequestMap(LifecycleContextHelper.java:72)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.context.LifecycleContextHelper.getLifecycleContext(LifecycleContextHelper.java:36)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.getLifecycleContext(ADFPhaseListener.java:167)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.dispatchAfterPagePhaseEvent(ADFPhaseListener.java:302)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Feb 26, 2016 1:52:07 PM IST> <Notice> <Diagnostics> <BEA-320068> <Watch "UncheckedException" in module "Module-FMWDFW" with severity "Notice" on server "DefaultServer" has triggered at Feb 26, 2016 1:52:07 PM IST. Notification details: 
WatchRuleType: Log 
WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID = 'WL-101020') OR (MSGID = 'WL-101017') OR (MSGID = 'WL-000802') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101020') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101017') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-000802')) 
WatchData: DATE = Feb 26, 2016 1:52:07 PM IST SERVER = DefaultServer MESSAGE = [ServletContext@2080288141[app:TestADFJavaApp module:ServiceCloudJavaApp path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.context.JSFRequestMapAdapter.getRequestMap(JSFRequestMapAdapter.java:29)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.context.LifecycleContextHelper.getRequestMap(LifecycleContextHelper.java:72)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.context.LifecycleContextHelper.getLifecycleContext(LifecycleContextHelper.java:36)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.getLifecycleContext(ADFPhaseListener.java:167)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.dispatchAfterPagePhaseEvent(ADFPhaseListener.java:302)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:88)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:489)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
 SUBSYSTEM = HTTP USERID = <WLS Kernel> SEVERITY = Error THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' MSGID = BEA-101020 MACHINE = USBLRAPATTAR1 TXID =  CONTEXTID = 0a2abd6a-a5e2-467e-a08d-ab49289bac6b-00000069 TIMESTAMP = 1456474927212  
WatchAlarmType: AutomaticReset 
WatchAlarmResetPeriod: 30000 
> 
<oracle.adf.common> <AdfDiagnosticsJarsVersionDumpImpl> <executeDump> <Path of the jars version dump :C:\Users\apattar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\adr\diag\ofm\defaultdomain\defaultserver\incident\incdir_26/adf_DiagnosticsJarsVersionDump11_i26.txt> 
<oracle.dfw.impl.incident.DiagnosticsDataExtractorImpl> <DiagnosticsDataExtractorImpl> <createADRIncident> <incident 27 created with problem key "DFW-99998 [java.lang.NullPointerException][oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.context.JSFRequestMapAdapter.getRequestMap][TestADFJavaApp]"> 
<oracle.adf.common> <AdfDiagnosticsJarsVersionDumpImpl> <executeDump> <Path of the jars version dump :C:\Users\apattar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\adr\diag\ofm\defaultdomain\defaultserver\incident\incdir_27/adf_DiagnosticsJarsVersionDump18_i27.txt>
```

Comment: Don't you have more details in the server logs ?

Comment: Error code 500 means internal server error. So please provide your complete stack trace from your server logs.

Comment: Okay! I thought something's wrong with my code so wanted to show my code first. I'll post the logs in text file and share the link

Comment: @Berger, http://textuploader.com/52wh3

Comment: @Anil, http://textuploader.com/52wh3

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception java.lang.Exception: MDSLockedSessionManager already registered. Can't register more than one.    at oracle.adf.share.mds.MDSTransManager.registerMDSLockedSessionManagerInst(MDSTransManager.java:131)

That means you have a duplicate entry on one of the meta data in your descriptors. Check your meta data xml files like weblogic-application.xml or the corresponding xml files.

Comment: ohk will check. Thanks